# How to show less number of pages on mobile view in Pagination?

Tags: css, reactjs, pagination, material-ui

**Problem**

Need to show less number of pages in mobile view so that it can be aligned with heading (My Orders) in the same line.

[image]

**Library**

[material-ui/pagination](https://material-ui.com/api/pagination/)

**Progress**

Able to remove *Next* and *Previous* content in the mobile view but neither able to find any out-of-the-box prop(s) nor any CSS to reduce number of pages in mobile view

*Web view*

[image]

*Mobile View*

[image]

**Code**

*CSS*

```
@media (min-width: 501px) {
.MuiPagination-root {
.MuiPagination-ul {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    li {
        &:first-child {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            > button::before {
                margin-right: 10px;
                content: "Previous  ";
            }
        }
        &:last-child {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
            > button::after {
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 20px;
                content: "  Next";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

*Custom Component*

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

    export const CustomPagination = ({ onChange, totalRecords, currentPage, className, shape }) => {
        return (
            <Pagination
                count={totalRecords}
                shape={shape}
                className={className}
                onChange={onChange}
                page={currentPage}
            />
        )
    };

    CustomPagination.propTypes = {
        paginationLength: PropTypes.number,
        selectPage: PropTypes.func,
        activePage: PropTypes.number,
    };
```

Comment: It seems Material UI's Pagination has poor set of properties. I think this is not a very good solution, but you can use useMediaQuery from Material UI and replace Pagination to the TablePagination when the resolution reaches the mobile one. Or find / create a new component.

Comment: Hi @Zain. I'm struggling with the same problem. Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Hi, @BrianH. in `material-ui/pagination` it is not possible unless you use external CSS so I have changed the design a little bit. Instead of showing less numbers, I have moved pagination to the next line with full width so that it could fit. Or you can try using another library if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions I came up with is wrapping the component pagination inside a Box then changing its size depending on the view :

```
export function Test() {
  return;
  <>
    <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "block" } }}>
      <Pagination
      />
    </Box>
    <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "block", md: "none" } }}>
      <Pagination
        size="small"
      />
    </Box>
  </>;
}
        </Box>
```